# Android Kotlin async/coroutines usage

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a function that runs on the Android main thread (**UI thread**):

```
fun someFunc() {

  ...
  doSomething1()
  doSomething2()
  doSomething3()
  ...
}
```

I want to run `doSomething2()` asynchronously in a **background thread** and make sure that `someFunc()` is suspended (not blocked) until this execution completes. Once done, `someFunc()` should resume in the main thread (from `doSomething3()`). During this background thread execution, I want to make sure that **main thread** is free and not blocked.

I know this can be done using `Futures`, but I'm wondering how to do this using `coroutines/async`?

Answer (score 1):

You can call those functions in a coroutine, launched using `viewModelScope` in a `ViewModel` class or `lifecycleScope` in `Activity`/`Fragment`:

```
fun someFunc() = viewModelScope.launch {

  doSomething1()
  doSomething2()
  doSomething3()

}

suspend fun doSomething2() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    ...
}
```

To run `doSomething2()` in a background thread we need to switch context of the coroutine to `Dispatchers.IO` using `withContext()` function.